How do I use Espresso Idling Resource with Kakao?
Im using following implementation of idling resource to wait for element to appear on screen before check is performed.
private class ViewPropertyChangeCallback(private val matcher: Matcher<View>, private val view: View) : IdlingResource, ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener {

    private lateinit var callback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback
    private var matched = false

    override fun getName() = "View property change callback"

    override fun isIdleNow() = matched

    override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(callback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback) {
        this.callback = callback
    }

    override fun onDraw() {
        matched = matcher.matches(view)
        callback.onTransitionToIdle()
    }
}

fun waitUntil(matcher: Matcher<View>): ViewAction = object : ViewAction {

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
        return Matchers.any(View::class.java)
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return StringDescription().let {
            matcher.describeTo(it)
            "wait until: $it"
        }
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        if (!matcher.matches(view)) {
            ViewPropertyChangeCallback(matcher, view).run {
                try {
                    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(this)
                    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnDrawListener(this)
                    uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle()
                } finally {
                    view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnDrawListener(this)
                    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
fun waitForElement(matcher: Matcher<View>) {
    onView(isRoot())
        .perform(waitUntil(hasDescendant(matcher)))
}

fun waitElement(element: Matcher<View>, matching: Matcher<View> = isDisplayed()) {
    waitForElement(Matchers.allOf(element, matching))
}

I am able to use this like:
fun waitForButton() {
    waitElement(withId(R.id.buttonId))
}

What I want to achieve is using Idling resource with Kakao KBaseView<*>
like:
private val buttonElement = KButton {withId(R.id.buttonId)}
fun waitForButton() {
    buttonElement.waitElement()
}

I have just started with automated testing on Android so I would appreciate any samples or tips on how to do this
